# Jquery disable click event for div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I got a simple click event for a HTML div.
If I click on the div it should trigger a fadeToggle.

In that div I got another div with another trigger.
On that click event it should do something but instead of doing the event it triggers the first event.

How do I prevent event 1 from triggering if I want event2 to trigger?

Event1 should trigger only if I don't press the clickevent on the second event everything else should trigger as usual.

Thanks for your time

**HTML**

```
<div id="1">
     Event 1
     <div id="2">
         <div id="3">
            but here is something as well event2
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#1").click(function() {
   $(this).slideToggle();
});


$("#3").click(function() {
   $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/VLcxJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#3").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

After that, clicks on #3 won't reach #2 or #1

Comment: Thank you. helped me out, I can accept your answer in 11 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.stopPropagation();` :

```
$("#e3").click(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

See it working here : http://jsfiddle.net/bYn22/

**Note from jQuery API** (I couldn't explain it better) : event.stopPropagation() > *Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.*

**And note that your IDs can't begin with a number** :)

Comment: It would be nice if you add an explanation of why he should be using `event.stopPropagation();` Now your answer looks as : Add this code and it would work

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#3").click(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

Added Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VLcxJ/1/

Comment: This is basically the same thing that I wrote :)

Comment: Of course, when I submitted the answer yours was no there yet on my browser, didn't meant to steal or anything.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution

```
        $("#1").click(function() {
            $(this).slideToggle();
        });


        $("#3").click(function(event) {
           event.stopPropagation();
            $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tR7h9/3/